# Double click on the next badge gear icon

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page

Double-clicking on the next badge gear in the profile page

> [image: gear]

leads to creation of two overlapped "Select your next badge" windows

> [image: win]

For the top most window mouse and keyboard events are not handled as expected. E.g. tab switching, filtering by name or selecting any badge is not working.

The only thing you can do with it - close it to see bottom (operable) window.

Comment: while I can see you think you are "double clicking" the system clearly thinks you are "clicking twice" and is responding accordingly.

Comment: @KateGregory "quoting" for images allows to see images borders more clearly, that's why I used it.

Comment: @Kate Sure, but even with two single clicks, the windows shouldn't overlap and both should be responsive.

Comment: @JasonC or the second click should be ignored

Comment: Is meta the place for bug reports? Cause it sure sounds like one... :)

Comment: Why only two clicks? Why not more than two?